# two custom cells in a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to use two custom cells inside a UITableView.  The problem I am running into is that my return is not being called in the right place.  I am not sure what I need to implement the return to stop the control from reaching the end of a non-void function.

Here is the code inside my cellforrowatindex.

```
static NSString *kCellID = @"MessageCell";
static NSString *UCellID = @"UnreadCell";
if (status == 0)
{
    //static NSString *kCellID = @"MessageCell";
    MessageListCell *cell = (MessageListCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];

        if (priority == 0)
        {
            cell. imageviewImportance.image = nil;
        }
        if (priority == 1)
        {
            cell.imageviewImportance.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"single exclamation.png"];
        }
        if (priority == 2)
        {
            cell.imageviewImportance.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"double exclamation mark.png"];
        }
        if (priority == 3)
        {
            cell.imageviewImportance.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"triple exclamation kmar.png"];
        }
//if (status == 0)
//{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.labelFrom.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"From: %@",m.From];
    cell.labelFrom.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    cell.labelSubject.text = subject;
    cell.labelSubject.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    cell.labelTime.text = time;
    cell.labelTo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"To: %@",m.To];
    cell.labelTo.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    return cell;
}
else if (status != 0)
{
    //static NSString *UCellID = @"UnreadCell";
    MessageListCell *cell = (MessageListCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:UCellID];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.unreadLabelFrom.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"From: %@",m.From];
    cell.unreadLabelSubject.text = subject;
    cell.unreadLabelTo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"To:%@",m.To];
    cell.unreadLabelTime.text = time;
    return cell;
}
//NSLog(@"description = %@",[cell description]);
//return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the `else if` to `else`, then the compiler will stop complaining.

The way you have it now is telling the compiler to check 2 condition, what if none of them are met? what is going to be returned?

You will need a `else` block but since your `else if` is redundant so `else` is what you need.

---

```
if (status == 0)
{
    static NSString *kCellID = @"MessageCell";
    MessageListCell *cell = (MessageListCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];

    NSString *imageName;
    switch (priority) {
        case 0:
            imageName = nil;
            break;
        case 1:
            imageName = @"single exclamation.png";
            break;
        case 2:
            imageName = @"double exclamation mark.png";
            break;
        case 3:
            imageName = @"triple exclamation kmar.png";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }


    cell.imageviewImportance.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.labelFrom.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"From: %@",m.From];
    cell.labelFrom.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    cell.labelSubject.text = subject;
    cell.labelSubject.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    cell.labelTime.text = time;
    cell.labelTo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"To: %@",m.To];
    cell.labelTo.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    return cell;
}
else
{
    static NSString *UCellID = @"UnreadCell";
    MessageListCell *cell = (MessageListCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:UCellID];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.unreadLabelFrom.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"From: %@",m.From];
    cell.unreadLabelSubject.text = subject;
    cell.unreadLabelTo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"To:%@",m.To];
    cell.unreadLabelTime.text = time;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: thank you.  would upvote the answer but don't have enough reputation points.  Thanks for you help.